# Embed YouTube video from custom field value

Tags: embed, videos, youtube

I'm collecting Youtube video links in custom fields, but when I echo out the value it just prints the URL. How do I get WordPress to convert it to be embedded?

Example:

```
<?php global $post;
$video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_video_link', true );
echo ( $video ); ?>
```

Just outputs `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkEvSjdDfiA`

But I want it to display the actual video...

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4):

Aha! WordPress has a built in function for it :D

```
<?php echo $embed_code = wp_oembed_get( $video ); ?>
```

Simples.